# How to force NVIDIA OpenCL to release GPU context to avoid memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, opencl, nvidia, mex

This is a follow up question to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091039/opencl-clcreatecontextfromtype-function-results-in-memory-leaks).

From the discussion, the mmc code (https://github.com/fangq/mmc) appears to be fine, and the memory was properly released when running on Intel CPU and AMD GPU. However, on NVIDIA GPU, `valgrind` reported significant memory leak, so was the test. Every time after a cycle of creating and releasing a GPU context, the memory kept increasing.

You can see this result in the below memory (blue line) profiling report.
[image]

Here is the test and commands to reproduce the issue (need to run this on NVIDIA GPUs):

```
git clone https://github.com/fangq/mmc.git
cd mmc/src
sed -i -e 's/mmc_init_from_cmd/for(int i=0;i<5;i++){\nmmc_init_from_cmd/g' mmc.c
sed -i -e 's/return/getchar();}\nreturn/g' mmc.c
make clean
make all
cd ../examples/validation
../../src/bin/mmc -f cube2.inp -G 1 -s cube2 -n 1e4 -b 0 -D TP -M G -F bin
```

run `../../src/bin/mmc -L` to list GPUs, use `-G #` to specify which GPU to use.

as you will see, the simulation will repeat 5 times, separated by enter keys. You can start a memory monitor, like `top` command in Linux, and see the increasing memory allocation after each repetition.

I googled and found multiple previous reports on OpenCL memory leaks, but I did not find an solution. I would like to know if if there any trick to force NVIDIA OpenCL driver to clean up memory after each run. I am asking this because mmc has a MATLAB/Octave mex function which can be called multiple times, and this issue could lead to large memory usage after multiple calls.

Comment: I know you are looking for the solution but have you tried to workaround the issue by using `libOpenCL.so` from different than Cuda source? Like from `ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64` package on Ubuntu. Also have you tried to use [POCL](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pocl)? It should support nvidia gpu too. Workarounding the issue might be your only bet...